# elasticsearch regex query to include forward slash

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following records in elastic search

```
{
  "label": "/home and garden/home furnishings",
  "score": "0.731174"
},
{
  "label": "/travel/vacation rentals",
  "score": "0.601932"
},
{
  "label": "/travel/vacation rentals",
  "score": "0.657443"
},
{
  "label": "/home and garden/gardening and landscaping/yard and patio",
  "score": "0.707792"
}
```

Now i want to make a query to get all taxonomy labels that start with "/travel" and i want the data only till the third forward slash

example if we take

```
 "label": "/home and garden/gardening and landscaping/yard and patio"
```

then i want the data only till

```
/home and garden/gardening and landscaping/
```

I tried some of the queries for it for partial match like:

```
{
 "_source":["taxonomy"],
  "from" : 0,
 "size" : 100,
 "query": {
     "regexp":{
    "taxonomy.label":{
        "value":"/travel.*",
        "boost":1.2
    }
}
}
```

}

But it does not seem to take the forward slashes as soon as i give slashes it stops giving any results, i want to know if this is possible or not and if it is then how do i proceed with this query?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your question you have mentioned  start with "/travel". thne how come it should match  "label": "/home and garden/gardening and landscaping/yard and patio" this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. first is querying documents which starts with `travel`. 
 For that you can try `path_hierarchy` from ElasticSearch. You can read more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html). 
This will allow you to store your path '`/travel/vacation rentals`' in the form of 
`/travel`
`/travel/vacation rentals`

after than you can do direct match query to that field.

For the second part you can try scripts, but be careful with them as enabling inline scripts can result in some unethical access if exposed to outside world.

You can go safe by using scripts kept in specific `scripts` folder. You can read more on scripts and how to make it secure [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html).